# Uninstall Application (.exe) is in Deleted Directory

Tags: vb.net, software-design

I am creating an Uninstall Tool for my application. The (.exe) is located within one of the folders that needs to be deleted.

When I try:

```
 IO.Directory.Delete("C:\Program Files\application_folder", True)
```

I get an error that the program is denied because it cannot find the specified path. 
Essentially, I am asking is there code or some software approach to handling how to delete the Uninstall (.exe) when it is in the folder I am deleting.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(
  "C:\OldDirectory",
  FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents) is how i do it.  Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.deletedirectory?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: This is why you use Windows Installer or ClickOnce or something else that is independent of your app to install and uninstall. Your uninstaller is an app itself so it can't delete itself while it's running.